# Определить уровень вложенности элемента меню, по которому кликнули

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как узнать по какому уровню вложенности меню кликнули?
Для такого `<li><a></a></li>`, - это последний элемент, или промежуточный? 
Желательно без присвоения дополнительных классов элементам и кроссбраузерно.
Если элемент *последний*, то при клике по нему, - выпадающий список нужно закрыть. Спасибо.

---

```js
var m = '';

document.getElementById('hmenu').addEventListener("click", menu_onclick);


function menu_onclick() {
  // - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
  // ? как узнать по какому уровню меню кликнули :
  //   - 1й уровень (Text_1, Text_2, Text_3)
  //   - 2й уровень (1, 2, 3)
  //   - 3й (a, b, c)
  // - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
  // ? как узнать на какой уровень кликнули :
  //   первый, промежуточный, или последний
  // - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
  var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
  if (target.style != m) {
    target.style.background = 'red';
    if (m != '') {
      m.background = '';
    }
    m = target.style;
  }
}
```

```css
#menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background: #ccc;
}
#hmenu {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
}
#hmenu li:nth-child(1) {
  width: 30%;
}
#hmenu li:nth-child(2) {
  width: 40%;
}
#hmenu li:nth-child(2) ul a {
  width: 150px;
}
#hmenu li:nth-child(2) >a:after {
  content: ' ▶';
  font-size: 12px;
}
#hmenu li:nth-child(2) li ul {
  background: #c6c6c6;
  left: 150px;
}
#hmenu li:nth-child(3) {
  width: 30%;
}
#hmenu li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
#hmenu li a {
  font-size: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
#hmenu li a:hover {
  background: goldenrod;
}
#hmenu li ul li {
  float: none;
}
#hmenu li ul li a {
  line-height: 25px;
}
#hmenu li ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #c3c3c3;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
#hmenu li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
#hmenu li ul li ul,
#hmenu li:hover ul li ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
#hmenu li ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="menu">
    <ul id="hmenu">

      <li><a>Text_1</a>
      </li>
      <li><a>Text_2</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a>1</a>
          </li>
          <li><a>2</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a>a</a>
              </li>
              <li><a>b</a>
              </li>
              <li><a>c</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a>3</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a>Text_3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

---

Comment: `var poslednij = $(this).find("li").length = 0;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь функциями навигации по дереву DOM и проверьте соседей текущего узла [Навигация по DOM-элементам](https://learn.javascript.ru/traversing-dom). Так же поможет поиск вложенных элементов [Поиск: getElement* и querySelector*](https://learn.javascript.ru/searching-elements-dom).

```
   if(target.parentNode.querySelector("ul") == null)
        console.log("последний элемент");
   if(target.parentNode.parentNode.id == "hmenu")
        console.log("элемент верхнего уровня");
```

```js
var m = '';

document.getElementById('hmenu').addEventListener("click", menu_onclick);


function menu_onclick() {
  // - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
  // ? как узнать по какому уровню меню кликнули :
  //   - 1й уровень (Text_1, Text_2, Text_3)
  //   - 2й уровень (1, 2, 3)
  //   - 3й (a, b, c)
  // - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
  // ? как узнать на какой уровень кликнули :
  //   первый, или последний
  // - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
  var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
  
  if(target.parentNode.querySelector("ul") == null)
    console.log("последний элемент");
  if(target.parentNode.parentNode.id == "hmenu")
    console.log("элемент верхнего уровня");
  
  
  if ( target.style != m ) {
       target.style.background = 'red';                    if (m != '') {
           m.background = '';                              }  
       m = target.style;
  }  
}
```

```css
#menu {
 width:100%;
 height:30px;
    background:#ccc;
}
#hmenu {
 width:100%;
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
 list-style-type:none;
    position:relative;
}

#hmenu li:nth-child(1) {
 width:30%;
}
#hmenu li:nth-child(2) {
 width:40%;
}
#hmenu li:nth-child(2) ul a{
   width:150px;
}
#hmenu li:nth-child(2) >a:after {
    content: ' ▶';
    font-size: 12px;
}
#hmenu li:nth-child(2) li ul {
   background:#c6c6c6;
   left:150px;
}
#hmenu li:nth-child(3) {
 width:30%;
}

#hmenu li{
 float:left;
    position:relative;
}
#hmenu li a{
 font-size:12px;
 text-decoration:none;
 display:block;
 line-height:30px;
    text-align: center;
}
#hmenu li a:hover{
 background: goldenrod;
}
#hmenu li ul li{
    float:none;
}
#hmenu li ul li a{
    line-height:25px;
}
#hmenu li ul{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    background-color: #c3c3c3;
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
}
#hmenu li:hover ul{
    display:block;
}
#hmenu li ul li ul,
#hmenu  li:hover ul li ul{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
}
#hmenu li ul li:hover ul{
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="menu">
<ul id="hmenu">

 <li><a>Text_1</a></li>   
 <li><a>Text_2</a>
    <ul>
       <li><a>1</a></li>
       <li><a>2</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a>a</a></li> 
                <li><a>b</a></li>
                <li><a>c</a></li>
            </ul> 
                </li>
       <li><a>3</a></li>
    </ul>
 </li>
 <li><a>Text_3</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Почему у Вас клик по верхнему уровню вызывает ещё и "последний элемент"?

Comment: Спасибо за ссылки и пояснения, Ваш код мне здорово помог.

Comment: @Other, элемент одновременно и верхнего уровня и является последним в ветке(не имеет у себя подменю). При желании две проверки можно объединить, но в качестве примера так более наглядно.

Comment: Не имеет, верно, но на уровне всего меню - это никак не последний уровень. Только верхний.

Comment: @Other, прочтите еще раз внимательней. Что вы подразумеваете под "последний уровень"? Это может быть как N-глубина всего дерева, так и глубина одной конкретно ветки. В данном случае на уровне ветки ничего не мешает элементу верхнего уровня быть последним в своей же ветке. О чем и идет речь, глубина всего дерева я тут понимаю не важна.

Comment: Видимо, вышло недопонимания. Я как раз говорил о уровне **всего** древа меню. Он тут, вроде, 3. Что ж, возможно, лишь возможно, Вы правы.

Answer (score 2):

Навесьте EventListener-ы на  - элементы, тогда можно будет определять следующим образом:

```js
var m = '';

//document.getElementById('hmenu').addEventListener("click", menu_onclick);
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
  links[i].addEventListener("click", menu_onclick);
}


function menu_onclick() {
  console.log(this.parentElement.getElementsByTagName('ul'));
  if(!this.parentElement.getElementsByTagName('ul').length) {
    //Последний уровень вложенности  
  }
  // - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
  // ? как узнать по какому уровню меню кликнули :
  //   - 1й уровень (Text_1, Text_2, Text_3)
  //   - 2й уровень (1, 2, 3)
  //   - 3й (a, b, c)
  // - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
  // ? как узнать на какой уровень кликнули :
  //   первый, промежуточный, или последний
  // - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

  var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
  if (target.style != m) {
    target.style.background = 'red';
    if (m != '') {
      m.background = '';
    }
    m = target.style;
  }
}
```

```css
#menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background: #ccc;
}
#hmenu {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
}
#hmenu li:nth-child(1) {
  width: 30%;
}
#hmenu li:nth-child(2) {
  width: 40%;
}
#hmenu li:nth-child(2) ul a {
  width: 150px;
}
#hmenu li:nth-child(2) >a:after {
  content: ' ▶';
  font-size: 12px;
}
#hmenu li:nth-child(2) li ul {
  background: #c6c6c6;
  left: 150px;
}
#hmenu li:nth-child(3) {
  width: 30%;
}
#hmenu li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
#hmenu li a {
  font-size: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
#hmenu li a:hover {
  background: goldenrod;
}
#hmenu li ul li {
  float: none;
}
#hmenu li ul li a {
  line-height: 25px;
}
#hmenu li ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #c3c3c3;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
#hmenu li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
#hmenu li ul li ul,
#hmenu li:hover ul li ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
#hmenu li ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="menu">
    <ul id="hmenu">

      <li><a>Text_1</a>
      </li>
      <li><a>Text_2</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a>1</a>
          </li>
          <li><a>2</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a>a</a>
              </li>
              <li><a>b</a>
              </li>
              <li><a>c</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a>3</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a>Text_3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Считать количество родительских контейнеров менюшки, наверное.

```js
let root = document.getElementById('hmenu');

root.addEventListener("click", menu_onclick);

function getLevel(el){
 let level = 0, current = null;

 while(current = el.closest('ul')){
  level++;

  if(current === root)
   break;
  else
   el = current.parentNode;
 }

 return level;
}

function menu_onclick(e){
  let target = e.target,
      level  = getLevel(target);
  
  console.info(level);
}
```

```css
#menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background: #ccc;
}
#hmenu {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
}
#hmenu li:nth-child(1) {
  width: 30%;
}
#hmenu li:nth-child(2) {
  width: 40%;
}
#hmenu li:nth-child(2) ul a {
  width: 150px;
}
#hmenu li:nth-child(2) >a:after {
  content: ' ▶';
  font-size: 12px;
}
#hmenu li:nth-child(2) li ul {
  background: #c6c6c6;
  left: 150px;
}
#hmenu li:nth-child(3) {
  width: 30%;
}
#hmenu li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
#hmenu li a {
  font-size: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
#hmenu li a:hover {
  background: goldenrod;
}
#hmenu li ul li {
  float: none;
}
#hmenu li ul li a {
  line-height: 25px;
}
#hmenu li ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #c3c3c3;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
#hmenu li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
#hmenu li ul li ul,
#hmenu li:hover ul li ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
#hmenu li ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="menu">
    <ul id="hmenu">

      <li><a>Text_1</a>
      </li>
      <li><a>Text_2</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a>1</a>
          </li>
          <li><a>2</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a>a</a>
              </li>
              <li><a>b</a>
              </li>
              <li><a>c</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a>3</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a>Text_3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

А какой уж последний или первый - это решайте сами, зависит от вашей задачи.
P. S. Закрыть/открыть что-то нельзя, т. к. реализация этих действий на CSS. А колдунство с классами не одобрено.

Comment: думал, возможна 'подмена' класса, - жаль. спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Напильник есть, возможность тоже. Пилите, Шура, пилите.

Comment: Other, примером кода не поможете ? по улучшению, или иное ... Вы точно подметили про "последний элемент" у уважаемого Alex Krass

Comment: Я и так показал направление. Или нужно всё сделать, тестами покрыть и на битбакет выложить?

Comment: Other, да, Вы всё грамотно сделали, просто у меня нет навыков.

Comment: Тогда 100 руб. на киви и будет рабочий скрипт.